# Info manuals not listed in Termux

Tags: info, manual, termux

I have Emacs installed through Termux.  The Emacs manuals (`emacs.info.gz`, etc.) are located at `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/info/`.  I can open them with `find-file`.  I don't see them with `C-h i`.

The INFOPATH is set in `~/.bashrc`:

```
# .bashrc
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/info/
```

A new Termux session shows the correct INFOPATH.  The path above is the `Info-default-directory-list` and is the last entry in `Info-directory-list`.

The texinfo, gzip, and zlib packages are installed in Termux.

I can see the manuals for Magit, use-package, etc. listed in  `*info*`.

How can I access the Emacs manuals through Info?

Comment: If you don't have a `dir` file in that directory, you need to create one. See the [Directory file dir](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Directory-File.html) section in the Texinfo manual.

Comment: No `dir`.  Seems like I need to use `install-info`, but I can't find the magic invocation of the correct arguments.

Comment: You have to provide more details: isn't `sudo make install-info` enough? How about `sudo make install-info prefix=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr`? How did they end up in that directory in the first place?

Comment: This works.  After running this script and restarting Termux/Emacs.  `for file in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/info/*
do
    install-info --info-file="$file" --dir-file=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/info/dir
done`.  If you make comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two components to the Info system: the info files themselves and a `dir` file which acts as the top level index. When Info sees more than one directory in `INFOPATH`, it merges all the `dir` files that it finds into one index. The corollary however is that the `dir` file must exist.

You can create the `dir` file by hand if you want: there is information about that in the [Texinfo manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Installing-an-Info-File.html), but in most cases, it is built when the info file for the package is installed.

In any case, since these are the standard emacs info files, you can reinstall them using the appropriate `make` invocation and get everything. GNU Makefiles make use of the `prefix` variable (`/usr/local` by default) to construct all the directories for the software installation. So all you have to do is override that destination:

```
sudo make install-info prefix=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr
```

That in turn uses the `install-info` program appropriately to add the various info files to the `dir` file in the info directory corresponding to the prefix (`$prefix/share/info`).

In fact, since the info files were already installed in that directory, the OP found it expedient to just run a small script to create the `dir` file from the existing info files instead of rerunning the `make`:

```bash
for file in /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/info/*
do
     install-info --info-file="$file" --dir-file=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/info/dir
done
```

Comment: it's
`--dir-file=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/info/dir`
not
`--dir-file=/data/data/com.termux/file/usr/share/info/dir`

Comment: Thank you - fixed.